# Id is not returned in the click of span in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning

I have below code in html and js,

```
<template for:each={teachers} for:item="item">
    <template if:false={item.isTeacherIdEmpty}>
        <span onclick={navigateToTeacher} key={item.teacherId} data-id={item.teacherId}>
                      <a href="#">{item.teacherName}</a>
                 </span>
        </template>
</template>

navigateToTeacher(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('event ', event.target.dataset.id);   //output is undefined
    console.log('event current ', event.currentTarget.dataset.id);  //output is undefined
        console.log('event innerhtml ', event.target.innerHTML); //output is name of the teacher (which is correct)
    }
```

When we click on the span, id was returning as undefined whereas the innerhtml was returning correctly so atleast the onclic was working. Not sure why id was not returning (id value is not empyt, which I have cross checked).

Comment: You can try this: `const elm = event.target.closest("[data-id]"); console.log('Id --> '+ elm.dataset.id);`

Comment: @Tushar this worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.target` is the element the event was targeted at, which may be inside your `data-id` element (like the `a` in your `div`). You can use the [closest method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) with an attribute presence selector ([[attribute-name]](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-representation)) to find the `data-id` element:

```
const elm = event.target.closest("[data-id]"); 
console.log('Id --> '+ elm.dataset.id);
```

That checks e.target to see if it matches the CSS selector and, if it doesn't, looks to its parent to see if it matches, and so on until it reaches the document root. If it gets all the way to the root without finding it, it returns null.